# Copy between matches, not the lines, but things between match-points

Tags: vim, matching

```
:/From book:/,/$/ cmd_copy chapters_from_match_@From_book@_until_end_of_line.txt
```

I tried not to use words "write", "put" or "read" as VIM has special meaning for them. I try to copy (sorry not referring to VIM's copy-command) the thing between matches to a file. How do you do it, without copying the whole lines?

**Dummy example**

**TEXT:**

> do not copy me dummy1 hello world
>   please copy me dummy2 do not copy me
>
> some enters, should work also with enters btw the matchpoints dummy1 not yet!
>
> not yet!
>
> copy will end soon! dummy2

**COPIED:**

> hello world please copy me

or

> dummy1 hello world please copy me dummy2

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question. Could you give us a dummy example with what it looks like BEFORE and AFTER?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To copy text between `start` and `end`, use the following sequence of Normal
mode commands.

> `/start/e+1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`y/end/`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

The first command searches for the next occurrence of the pattern matching
start of a text fragment to copy, and positions the cursor to the first
character after the match.  The second one yanks everything until the next
match of the ending pattern.

Depending on the context in which the commands will be used, they could be
rewritten as an Ex command, a mapping or a macro.

- Ex command

  ```
  :norm!/start/e+1^My/end/
  ```

  (Type `^M` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)
- Mapping

  ```
  :nnoremap <leader>y /start/e+1<cr>y/end/<cr>
  ```
- Macro

  ```
  :let @y = "/start/e+1\ry/end/\r"
  ```

  (Or record a macro the usual way: type `q`, register to store the
  macro, say, `y`, then commands as it shown at the top of the answer
  followed by final `q`.)

Answer (score 0):

so, why not use

```
:1s/^\_.\{-}dummy1//    "first line: delete everything until first occurrence of dummy1
:%s/dummy2\zs\_.\{-}\zedummy1/\n/
:1s/\_.*dummy2\zs\_.*// "delete from last occurrence of dummy2 till EOF
```